# MVC 5 multiple models in a single form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, entity-framework, entity

I have a `ViewModel` which contains person data which will be assigned to a `Person` model, this `ViewModel` also has an `Address` model and the person has an `AddressId` to link that person to the `Address`.

The problem I am having is, when I map the `ViewModel` to the `Person` and set the `EntityState` to `Modified` only the `Person` table will get updated *and* a **new** `Address` will be added (if it has been changed) instead of being updated.

EDIT:

Models:

```
public class Address : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Line One"), MaxLength(128)]
    [Index("IX_AddressCollectiveUniqueness", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public String LineOne { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Line Two"), MaxLength(128)]
    [Index("IX_AddressCollectiveUniqueness", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public String LineTwo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Line Three"), MaxLength(128)]
    [Index("IX_AddressCollectiveUniqueness", 3, IsUnique = true)]
    public String LineThree { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(32)]
    [Index("IX_AddressCollectiveUniqueness", 4, IsUnique = true)]
    public String Parish { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(16)]
    [Index("IX_AddressCollectiveUniqueness", 5, IsUnique = true)]
    public String Island { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(8)]
    [Index("IX_AddressCollectiveUniqueness", 6, IsUnique = true)]
    public String Postcode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public class Person : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? AddressId { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "First Name"), MaxLength(32)]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Middle Name"), MaxLength(64)]
    public String MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Last Name"), MaxLength(32)]
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class PersonManageVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? AddressId { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(4)]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "First Name"), MaxLength(32)]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Middle Name"), MaxLength(64)]
    public String MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Last Name"), MaxLength(32)]
    public String LastName { get; set; }

}
```

The controller is almost identical to the generated update method, it just sets the entitystate and saves.

Comment: Can you show mapping between this objects?

Comment: Show your view and the controller methods (do you have a hidden input for the `AddressId` so it posts back?

Comment: First check that you do not losing the primary key of Address while mapping between viewmodel and the class Person.

Comment: @PawełMaga Check that, it is passing everything it needs back but it still creates a new entry in the address table.

Comment: Here is solution for similar problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381304/updating-related-data-using-mvc-4-and-entity-framework
Check that

Comment: @PawełMaga I had a look at that and tried a few things out. It seems to think my Address object isn't a complex type so I can't use `entry.Property(e => e.Address.LineOne).IsModified = true;`